Clear the select option whenever changes with the onchange event in React
I want to make a dropdown select option element with depedent values. I want these values to be stored in an object with setState. The problem is I want in the first option to clear first the object and then set the value of the option with onchange event.What I get is that when I change the option the value is not cleared. Instead the changed value is added to object value
the click function takes an array with the data and set the value of the target
 const BusinessForm = ({business}) => {
    




const [newarr,setValues] = useState({})

const [selects,setSelect] = useState([])
const arr = flattenObj(business.options)
// console.log(arr)
// console.log(arr)
const click = (value,array) =>{
    // console.log(value)
    //[{category:[{sub:[]},{sub:[]}]},{category:[{sub:[]},{sub:[]}]}]
    
        
        const temp = array.filter((ob)=>ob[value])[0]
        
        const temparr = []
        temp[value].forEach((s)=>{
            
            if(typeof s==='object'){
                // console.log(Object.keys(s)[0])
                temparr.push(Object.keys(s)[0])
            }else{
                temparr.push(s)
            }
            
        })
        
        if(newarr==={}){
            setValues({[value]:temparr})
        }else{
            setValues({...newarr,[value]:temparr})
        }
        
        
       
}



// const insertselects = (option)=>{
//     if(option!=null){
//         console.log(option)
//     }
// }
// insertselects(newarr)
console.log(newarr)

    return ( 
        <div>
            <h5>
                this is a businessform for {business.business_name}
            </h5>
           
         
           
            <select name="" id="" onChange={(e)=>{
           
               click(e.target.value,arr)
               
            }}  defaultValue={Object.keys(arr)[0]} >
                    {
                        arr.map((el)=>(
                           Object.keys(el).map((k)=>(
                            <option value={k}  key={k} >{k}</option>
                           ))
                        ))
                }
            </select>
            
           
               
           
        </div>
     );
}

Any thoughts?

do you want to reset the select when one option is seleted?

I want to set the value of newarr to {} before I set values to newarr. I mean I want to have a setValues({}) in the click() function  that resets value to {} of newarr whenever the value is changed with the onchanged event and then continue with what the function is already doing
